# CSS multiple pseudo selector and tilde, how to

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I have this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/srlopez/pen/RRgPNB) to test a DropDown sidebar.
Does not use JS, only plain CSS, and show/hide `ul`, if a hidden `input` checkbox type is clicked. 
It works except from selecting the `ul` to show/hide because select all the `ul` at the same level from  the checked input

Need help to apply the correct selector
This `dropdown input:checked ~ ul` select all the ul, but this `dropdown input:checked ~ ul:first-child` does not select any!

The code is available [here](https://codepen.io/srlopez/pen/RRgPNB)

Thanks to http://codepen.io/Duval_Ruilova/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to a site or an example**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `input ~ ul` as that means "any ul that comes after the input"

Instead use `input + label + ul` to mean specifically "the ul that's after the label that's after the input".